# What could be injecting body style="zoom: 0.71" into some pages on chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, zoom

I don't know how long this has gone on, but something is inserting `style="zoom: 0.71;"` into the body tag of some pages in Google Chrome.

[image]

I have:

- Reset all zoom controls to 100% (View->Actual Size)
- Deleted all "Zoom Levels" in Privacy->Content Settings
- Disabled all themes (Clicked "Use Classic Theme")
- Closed and reopened Chrome to ensure all settings have been set.

Some more points:

- It appears to be only some pages that are affected.
- Firefox doesn't do this, so it's definitely being done by Chrome.
- Accessing exactly the same page from another machine with the same OS and version of Chrome doesn't have the zoom, either.  So I suspect that it's a setting I've triggered somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, while writing this question, I realised that I hadn't tried disabling all extensions.  * facepalm *

It turns out that one of my extensions had a facility which zoomed the page by injecting a zoom style into the body instead of using the browser's zoom as I had expected.

However, I'm not going to name the plugin because I'm not here to advertise.

Moral to this story:  **Disable all plugins/extensions** as well as disabling themes, etc. when looking for browser issues.